# How to create and display user content submission form?

Tags: users, nodes, forms

Drupal 7

Could someone point me to the right direction on how to create a submission form through which users can post content? I have a specific content type that I expect the users to fill in while submitting.

I know it's horrible, but i was thinking to link to the relevant admin page, but there must be a better way (something like Views but for submission forms)

Thanks, Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create content pages are separate from Drupal's admin section. You can set up the permissions so users can add content of a specific content type but don't have access to any other content types or the admin section.

There's also a permission 'View the administration theme' if this isn't set for a particular role, but they can add content, then the Create Content page will use the default theme. There's also a setting at the bottom of the appearance page, if you deselect 'Use the administration theme when editing or creating content' then everyone who accesses the create content pages will use the default theme also.

Comment: How would you style the node/add form for anonymous users only?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow anonymous users to submit content using the node/add form, but consider some precautions:

- Keep the nodes unpublished (if possible) until an admin can approve
- Any text box should have limited HTML options
- Any links should be set to rel="nofollow"
- Set up a rule to email an admin whenever node of that type has been added